# Error when using a saved model for predicting to raster in R

Tags: r, raster

```
save(ranger_tree1000, file="FinalModels/ranger.Rdata", overwrite=T)

load(file = "C:/Users/bhauptman/Box/Ch2/R/FinalModels/ranger.Rdata")

r_ranger <- raster::predict(model = ranger, object = Rstack)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
      no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "function"
```

Comment: What type of object is Rstack?

Comment: A raster stack tif file. And it works with predict and other models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model is called `ranger_tree1000`, not `ranger`, so you should be able to do:

```
r_ranger <- raster::predict(model = ranger_tree1000, object = Rstack)
```

Using `save` is rather outdated and makes for mysterious code, as you do not know the names of the objects you are loading. It is much better to use `saveRDS` and `readRDS` like this

```
saveRDS(ranger_tree1000, "FinalModels/ranger.Rds")
ranger <- readRDS("FinalModels/ranger.Rds")
```

(and note that neither `save`, nor `saveRDS` has an argument called `overwrite`)